# What is the format of the DataContractAttribute.Namespace Property?

Tags: wcf, namespaces, datacontract, servicecontract

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff183866.aspx) recommends always to provide a namespace to a ServiceContract and DataContract.

Examples usually have a "schema" prefix and a URI type pattern for the namespace such as

`Namespace="urn:WCFEssentials/Samples/2008/12"`

instead of a traditional C# namespace with dot-notation such as

`Namespace="MyNamespace.MyDataClasses"`

What is the suggested format the namespace property? Do we need the schema prefix? Why is this format suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [XML Namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace).  Those can either be in the `urn:` format or they can be URLs.

Comment: Here is more info from W3 on the "urn" prefix: http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/URI_URN.html

Answer (score 3):

Here are some additional suggestions from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff183866.aspx):

- The namespace can be *any* string
- but is traditionally a Uri representative of the company or application domain
- and includes a year and month to support versioning scenarios.
- For `DataContracts`, the namespace is often similar to the `ServiceContract` namespace
- but uses  using a “schemas” uri section

Example Service Contract with Namespace

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="urn:CompanyName/ApplicationName/YYYY/MM")]
[ServiceContract(Namespace="urn:BigFont/EmailSystem/2014/03")]
```

Example Data Contract with "Schema" Segment in Namespace

```
[DataContract(Namespace="urn:CompanyName/Schema/YYYY/MM")]
[DataContract(Namespace="urn:BigFont/Schema/2014/03")]
```

Thank you to John Saunders or getting me started.